# Why sometimes I debug a program in VS2010, my ctrl is pressed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have be driven mad. **Sometimes** I press F5 to debug, and I often press shift+F5 to exit debug, but it restart debug(shortcut of restart debug is ctrl+shift+F5). If I click some var it will navigate its definition. I just find I must press ctrl again lonely will disable it.
Anyone know why? Thx.

Comment: Even after tool restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue.
There are indeed multiple Connect tickets ([1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534915/stop-debugging-shortcut-key-shift-f5-causes-debugging-to-restart-instead-of-just-stopping), [2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619714/shift-f5-restart-debug-session-instead-of-stop-debugging), [3](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540234/after-pressing-shift-f5-is-re-launching-the-application-in-debug-mode), [4](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683604/shift-f5-debugging-bug-is-not-resolved-in-sp1)) on this problem. The [latest one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683604/shift-f5-debugging-bug-is-not-resolved-in-sp1) states:

> Thanks for reaching out to us. The original bug is indeed fixed in our current internal builds but that fix was not included in VS 2010 SP1. Keep an eye out for announcements of pre-release builds of the next version of Visual Studio as they will have the fix in them.
>
> Thanks!
>
> -Sean Laberee
>
> VS Pro Team

This basically sounds like "it won't get fix, but VS11 shouldn't have the problem anymore."

A good workaround is to disable the Ctrl+Shift+F5 shortcut for restarting debugging under *Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard...*.